# How can I get the claimsidentity of a token or from an token oauth2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I need one of my drivers to access certain information stored in the ClaimsIdentity.
Below my method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials().

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
    string rol = null;
    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Role"))
    {
        rol = context.Request.Headers.Get("X-Role");
        switch (rol)
        {
            case "user":
                bool isValidCredentials = await //Logica que verifica credenciales.
                if (isValidCredentials)
                {
                    //Crea y prepara el objeto ClaimsIdentity
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
                    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"email", context.UserName}
                    };
                    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(data);
                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
                    context.Validated(ticket);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    context.SetError("Invalid user or password.");
                    return;
                }
            case "things":
                //Logica para autenticar things.
                return;
            default:
                context.SetError("The role is not valid.");
                return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.SetError("The role header is required.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Part of the code of the controller dodne I need to have access to the claims is below

```
    [Route("{email}")]
    [Authorize(Roles="user")]
    public async Task<Customer> Get([FromUri]  string email)
    {
        //here I need to obtain the value of the claim that refers to userName associated with this identity.


    }
```

How could this behavior be achieved? I know that at least the value of Role is being obtained since this makes [Authorize (Roles = "user")] work.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your controller class inherits from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.
In this case you can access user claims in the following way.

At first get a ClaimsIdentity:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (this.User as ClaimsPrincipal)?.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var claimsIdentity = this.User?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

Then access claims:

```
if (claimsIdentity != null)
{
    string userName = claimsIdentity.Name;
    //or
    userName = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
}
```

Comment: It's just what I was looking for, thank you very much

Comment: @lavilaso, you are welcome! Could you accept the answer if this case?